# Flash AS3 toggle visible

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have a script that once clicked ( a button ) some other thing hides then once clicked again it re-shows. the problem is once hidden it never shows again here is the script:

```
menu_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickFunction);


function myClickFunction(event:MouseEvent) {

      // Hide the first and show the next here
      if (menu_menu.visible == true){
      menu_menu.visible = false;

      } 
      if (menu_menu.visible == false) {
          menu_menu.visible == true;
      }

}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Is there anything else happening to the menu_menu DisplayObject when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The reason is when you click on the
>   button, it does hide but again when
>   you click on the same button it does
>   not show back

Correct me if i am wrong in the above statement.

Now try something on what i say, have two buttons Hide and Show. Create two new function and try it out, if this works then there is something you are missing in your logic, if this does not work then let us know.

Also try this.

```
function myClickFunction(event:MouseEvent) {

      // Hide the first and show the next here
      if (menu_menu.visible){
      menu_menu.visible = false;

      } else {
         menu_menu.visible = true;
      }

}
```

The other issue could be, when you click on the button may be its not getting the menu_menu property again as its hidden or destroyed. Is it inside the same component or called from somewhere else?

Comment: "menu_menu.visible == true;" should be "menu_menu.visible = true;" because the value "true" needs to be assigned not tested.

Answer (score 10):

I prefer to write such logic in short form:

```
menu_menu.visible = !menu_menu.visible;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second "if" statement you are not assigning .visible to true but instead checking to see if it's equal to true because of the two equal signs.

```
function myClickFunction(event:MouseEvent) {

  // Hide the first and show the next here
  if (menu_menu.visible == true){
  menu_menu.visible = false;

  } 
  if (menu_menu.visible == false) {
      menu_menu.visible = true;
  }
```

}

Comment: You are missing an else before the last if statement which is why it is not hiding anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a better version based on Glens suggestion that I made, feel free to use.

```
Buttonname.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, FunctionName);
function FunctionName(event:MouseEvent) {

  if (name1.alpha == 1){
  name1.alpha = 0;} else {name1.alpha = 1}
}
```

What this script is saying is if name1 (a Movie Clip symbol) has an Alpha value equal to 1 when clicked then it will then change the Alpha value to 0, otherwise it will change the Alpha value to 1.

This will also work with the "visible" functions:

```
Buttonname.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, FunctionName);
function FunctionName(event:MouseEvent) {

  if (name1.visible == true){
  name1.visible = false;} else {name1.visible = true}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using alpha = 0.1 instead of visible = false and alpha = 1 instead of visible = true.

The problem is that when you use visible = false it also disables mouse interaction so your second click never fires.